# zsh: no matches found: bertopic[visualization]

Tags: python-3.x, pip, bert-language-model

I am trying to install bertopic[visualization] in my macbook pro using

```
pip3 install bertopic[visualization]
```

but I am getting an error whenever I am running the above command. The error is as given below:

```
zsh: no matches found: bertopic[visualization]
```

Is there any way to install bert's visualization option?

Comment: what version of ```Pytorch``` you are using? It is recommended to use ```pytorch1.4.0``` and above to install this package

Comment: @think-maths my pytorch version is 1.7.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+zsh%3A+no+matches+found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zsh` uses square brackets for [pattern matching](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l137) which means that if you need to pass literal square brackets as an argument to a command, you either need to escape them or quote the argument like this:

so try using:

`pip3 install 'bertopic[visualization]'`